# Would event listeners prevent garbage collecting objects referenced in outer function scopes?

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-leaks, reference, garbage-collection

Let's assume I have the following code:

```js
(function () {

    const largeObject = provideSomeLargeObject();
    const largeStaticListOfElements = document.querySelectorAll('span');
    const someElementThatWillBeRemoved = document.getElementById('i-will-be-removed');

    const elms = document.getElementsByClassName('click-me');

    for (let i = 0; i < elms.length; ++i) {

        const anotherLargeObject = provideAnotherLargeObject();

        elms[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            // callback just uses i, which contains a literal value
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(i);
        });
    }

    // largeObject, largeStaticListOfElements, someElementThatWillBeRemoved, and anotherLargeObject
    // are no longer used in this code. Should they be set to null to allow GC them?

})();
```

The event listeners create function scopes, and after executing the above code, the event listeners still exist, thus the outer function scopes are preserved so that the event handlers can use the variables they contain.

However, the event handlers just use some literal value from the outer scopes, but in these scopes there are other variables, that are not used anymore.

- Would the event listeners prevent garbage collecting the objects referenced by these variables, so I have to manually assign null to the variables at the end of the code,
- or are JavaScript engines smart enough to detect that the event handler never uses the variables, so the referenced objects can be GC even if the variables reside in a still existing function scope?

Answer (score 0):

Note that variables come in 2 flavors - primitives and objects. Primitives exists in a scope, you can't reference them outside its own and child scopes (they are copied by value).

So in your example you just don't care since you use a primitive only. If you remove event listeners or remove the elements from DOM, the whole construct is garbage collected (if the elements aren't referenced elsewhere).

If you use objects and reference them outside the scope, you are in trouble and use `reference = null` for all outside references so the construct is garbage collected.

Comment: The event listeners are still used on the web page, but their outer scopes contain large objects that are not used anymore (and aren't used anywhere else), and also references to other DOM elements, that may get removed afterwards. So, would you say that the event listeners prevent GC these objects and these removed DOM elements?

Answer (score -1):

It’s not so much the event listeners, but how you declare each and every identifier throughout.

So if you’re seriously concerned about the *Garbage Collector* doing its job (and you should be), you might want to refrain from declaring everything as constants, unnecessarily!

Examples of **GOOD** constant declarations...

```
const DaysOfWeek=['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

const MyName='John Citizen';

const CompanyHome='https://ourcompany.com/';
```

Examples of **BAD** constant declarations...

```
const largeObject = provideSomeLargeObject();

const largeStaticListOfElements = document.querySelectorAll('span');

const someElementThatWillBeRemoved = document.getElementById('i-will-be-removed');

const elms = document.getElementsByClassName('click-me');
```

You get the drift...

**NB:** The Garbage Collector CANNOT collect constant declarations for they are pushed to the top of the code section by the O/S, where their exact size is preserved in memory throughout the page running, given that they can never grow or shrink in size; for they can never change their value.

Comment: In JavaScript, the meaning of "const" slightly differs from the usual meaning. Usually, "const" are values that are globally defined (and of course constant). Whereas in JavaScript, it's just regular variables, but that cannot be redeclared (mainly to prevent programming errors). For instance, MDN [recommends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Writing_guidelines/Writing_style_guide/Code_style_guide/JavaScript#variable_declarations) to use "const" wherever possible, thus using "let" only when the variable is expected to be reassigned.